# Why does sizeof(array) return three times more than indexes in the array?

Tags: c++, arrays, for-loop, sizeof

I wanted to print an array in a for loop, but not only the array prints random numbers, but also prints 3 times more numbers than the boundaries of the array, which is weird since i am using sizeof(A) so it only prints until the bounds of it. Would you guys know why it prints several more times than specified in the code?

the code I tried is as follows:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
        int A[] = {1, 2, 4, 8, 16, 32, 64, 128};
        for (int i = 0; i < sizeof(A); i++) {
                cout << A[i] << endl;
        }
}
```

The output is as follows:

1
2
4
8
16
32
64
128
14294328
0
14294384
11
14294320
0
794104558
32759
0
0
62
0
794128456
32759
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0

As you can see, there are 32 outputs when the amount of prints was supposed to be only the amount as the size of the array.

The output I was hoping for with the code is:
1
2
4
8
16
32
64
128

Comment: Do you know what sizeof does ?

Comment: Three times more means a factor of 4. The size of an `int` would not happen to be 4 in your environment? Note that `sizeof()` answers in bytes, not in indexes. When doing C++, avoid C constructs by the way. If you would use C++ containers, you'd have more intuitive options to determines the range of useable entries. Are you aware of `std::array` or `std::vector`?

Comment: `sizeof(A)` does not do what you think it does. It returns amount of bytes occupied by the array object. To get amount of items in array use [::std::size](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator/size).

Comment: You really should not be using "C" style arrays in C++ anymore. Use `std::array<int,8> A{1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8};` you can then pass the array around like any other C++ variable (even return it from functions) and you can use `A.size();` to get its size. (There is no runtime overhead since size() is constexpr and can be evaluated at compile time)

Comment: i did in the ```std::array<int,8> A{1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8};``` way, but now, how can i put it sintatically such that i do not need to specify the size in ```<int, 8>```, since i need to put it in a method, such as ```void mergeSort(array <int, n> A)``` for example?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The expression with the `sizeof` operator `sizeof(A)` yields the size in bytes of the array `A`. The obtained value is equal to the number of elements in the array multiplied by the size of element of the array that is

```
sizeof( A ) = 8 * sizeof( int )
```

So if you have an array size and know the type of elements of the array you can get the number of elements in the array like

```
size_t n = sizeof( A ) / sizeof( A[0] )
```

It means that your for loop should be rewritten like

```
for ( size_t i = 0, n = sizeof( A ) / sizeof( A[0] ); i < n; i++ ) {
//...
```

From the C++17 Standard (8.3.3 Sizeof)

> 1 The sizeof operator yields the number of bytes in the object
> representation of its operand. The operand is either an expression,
> which is an unevaluated operand (Clause 8), or a parenthesized
> type-id. The sizeof operator shall not be applied to an expression
> that has function or incomplete type, to the parenthesized name of
> such types, or to a glvalue that designates a bit-field. sizeof(char),
> sizeof(signed char) and sizeof(unsigned char) are 1. The result of
> sizeof applied to any other fundamental type (6.9.1) is
> implementation-defined. [ Note: In particular, sizeof(bool),
> sizeof(char16_t), sizeof(char32_t), and sizeof(wchar_t) are
> implementation-defined.

Pay attention to that there is standard C++ function `std::size()` declared in header `<iterator>` that can be use instead of the expression with the `sizeof` operator

```
#include <iterator>

//...

for ( size_t i = 0, n = std::size( A ); i < n; i++ ) {
//...
```

But before introducing the standard C++ function std::size there was used data member `value` of structure `std::extent` declared in header `<type_traits>`.

Another approach is to use range-based for loop like

```
for ( const auto &item : A ) {
        cout << item << endl;
}
```

Also you could use iterators in the for loop or a standard algorithm like `std::copy` or `std::for_each`.

Here is a demonstration program that shows possible ways to output an array

```
#include <iostream>
#include <type_traits>
#include <iterator>
#include <algorithm>

int main()
{
    int A[] = { 1, 2, 4, 8, 16, 32, 64, 128 };

    //  using the sizeof operator
    for (size_t i = 0, n = sizeof( A ) / sizeof( A[0] ); i < n; i++)
    {
        std::cout << A[i] << ' ';
    }
    std::cout << '\n';

    //  using function std::size()
    for (size_t i = 0, n = std::size( A ); i < n; i++)
    {
        std::cout << A[i] << ' ';
    }
    std::cout << '\n';

    //  using std::extent_v
    for (size_t i = 0, n = std::extent_v<decltype( A )>; i < n; i++)
    {
        std::cout << A[i] << ' ';
    }
    std::cout << '\n';

    //  using range-based for loop
    for ( const auto &item : A )
    {
        std::cout << item << ' ';
    }
    std::cout << '\n';

    //  using for loop with iterators
    for (auto first = std::begin( A ), last = std::end( A ); first != last; ++first)
    {
        std::cout << *first << ' ';
    }
    std::cout << '\n';

    //  using algorithm std::copy
    std::copy( std::begin( A ), std::end( A ),
        std::ostream_iterator<int>( std::cout, " "));
    std::cout << '\n';

    //  using algorithm std::for_each
    std::for_each( std::begin( A ), std::end( A ),
        []( const auto &item )
        {
            std::cout << item << ' ';
        } );
    std::cout << '\n';

}
```

The program output is

```
1 2 4 8 16 32 64 128 
1 2 4 8 16 32 64 128 
1 2 4 8 16 32 64 128 
1 2 4 8 16 32 64 128 
1 2 4 8 16 32 64 128 
1 2 4 8 16 32 64 128 
1 2 4 8 16 32 64 128
```

Comment: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator/size says it's also declared in pretty much every collection header. Also, the `std::[s]size()` return type may be `std::[s]size_t`, `std::ptrdiff_t`, or `decltype(C::size)` where `C` is a generic collection. not guaranteed to be same; the correct usage in the indexed `for` is infer it with `auto`. Finally, since `std::[s]size()` is `constexpr`, the premature optimization with the `n` in your second from the end example is not only unnecessary, but potentially harmful, since the the `n` is mutable.

Comment: I think we better stop explaining "C" style arrays and explain std::array instead.

Comment: On an unrelated note, `size_t` is not guaranteed to be defined in C++, and `ssize_t` even in older C; use `std::[s]size_t` instead. This had in fact been the case with `ssize_t` (absent) vs `std::ssize_t` (defined) in MSVC and Intel compilers on Windows till at least v16. `ssize_t` is required by POSIX C (in `<sys/types.h>) but the ANSi C prior to ISO/IEC 9899:2011 aka C11 (which added `ssize_t` in <stdint.h>) had been quite more conservative (e.g., `//` comments were added only in C95).

Comment: @PepijnKramer The question is explicitly about arrays and using teh sizeof operator with arrays. You will not lnwo C++ if you know nothing anout arrays and teh sizeof operator.:)

Comment: @PepijnKramer I think we shouldn't. They're not deprecated as of C++23 for a reason. Pre-C++20 `std::array` is unwieldy to use, you need explicit template size parameter N, and matching length of the initializer list. `std::array<T,N>` doesn't decay to `T*`. ND `std::array` is not a thing. In the ideal beautiful world full of rainbows and unicorns, C++ arrays aren't required. In the real world, though, there are libraries such as BLAS and MKL.

Comment: @VladfromMoscow There is always confusion with sizeof and decayed pointers :( So I prefer to point out the alternative. And "C" style arrays (pointer decay) in my experience have lead to many bugs in the past (moving to vector/array can prevent quite a lot of them)

Comment: @kkminactive-supportstrike With CTAD std::array is already a bit more friendly, but I prefer using it over getting bugs (specialy when arrays need to be returned from functions).  For interop with libraries there still is the .data() function (on both vector and array).  But I can agree to not fully agree ;)

Comment: @PepijnKramer It is not a question about what you prefer. It is a question about arrays and the sizeof operator applied to an array that each beginner that starts to learn C++ shall know very well.

Comment: @VladfromMoscow I think we have different philosophies. I would first teach people to write C++ (using C++ core guideline principles) so they know how to use standard library stuff well before going into the details of memory layout etc. Knowing sizeof and a lot of other things are essential top but at a later stage (when people need to implement their own datastructures etc. Which I think should be the advanced topic. Just a classic top/down versus bottom/up approach I think.  :)

Comment: @PepijnKramer There's no partial CTAD, and without template arguments `std::array` is unreadable. Try `std::array a {1, -1, 0xBAADF00D};`. What is `decltype(a)::value_type`? Hint: it's not a 64-bit signed integer. Answer: https://godbolt.org/z/MaeK4vdGW. How about the typing helper `std::array a = std::to_array<long>(1, -1);`? Uh, no cigar: https://godbolt.org/z/sdz4Won8c. Exercise: rewrite https://godbolt.org/z/bnGbPTEGe using `std::array`. Possible, but ugly. Whatever you do, C++ loves you. For those who can't avoid “confusion with sizeof and decayed pointers,” there's always Haskell.

Comment: @PepijnKramer Your comments are irrelevant to the question and the answer. Nobody is interesting here what you prefer and about your philosophy. The question is very concrete about using arrays, the sizeof operator and for loop to output elements of an array. It is the basic knowledge that each programmer needs to learn before moving further. The author of the question wants to know why his code does not work. He is not asking a somebody  advice what to use and how to learn C++.

Comment: i did in the ```std::array<int,8> A{1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8};``` way, but now, how can i put it sintatically such that i do not need to specify the size in ```<int, 8>```, since i need to put it in a method, such as ```void mergeSort(array <int, n> A)``` for example?

Comment: I think the best outcome from this discussion tbh was that i just realized that when using C++ in vs code, there is also C code in it. Since I am trying to learn C++, i will follow with the std:: way, but thanks for clarifying the other way :D

Comment: @EduardoMarinho: “how can i [not] specify the size in `<int, 8>`”: C++17 and later, use CTAD: `std::array A {1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8};`. But it's not readable, as the array item type is not obvious. “i need to put it in a method...”: beware, the compiler will emit code for every `n` separately. The method should be generic, and you may run into missing deduction guides pre-C++20. This stuff is very much not for a beginner! “I am trying to learn C++, i will follow with the std:: way”: I'd learn both if I were you. That's unless you don't plan to work with real world C++ codebases ever...

Answer (score 7):

In C++, like C, `sizeof(x)` gives you the size in **bytes** of `x`. For arrays, you can use the usual trick `sizeof(x)/sizeof(x[0])` to get the **number of elements**.

You can think of it as dividing the total size in bytes by the size of one element in bytes.

Note that this trick won't work when the array is passed as an argument to a function as C-style arrays decay to pointers (i.e. the function won't have the information of the array's size).

That being said, `std::array` is generally better to use as an abstraction over regular C-style arrays, notably due to the compatibility with the standard algorithms, such as `std::for_each`, but also range for loops:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <array>

int main()
{
    std::array<int, 8> A;

    for (int item : A) {
        std::cout << item << endl;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

> The C++ sizeof operator is a unary operator that calculates the size of data type, variables, and constants at compile time. The size returned from the operator is multiple of the size of char, which in most computers is 1 byte (8 bits). The value returned from the sizeof() operator is of the type size_t.

So modify your code as follow:

```
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    int A[] = {1, 2, 4, 8, 16, 32, 64, 128};
    int size = sizeof(A) / sizeof(A[0]);  // Calculate the number of elements

    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
        std::cout << A[i] << std::endl;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

output:

```
1
2
4
8
16
32
64
128
```